# Adblock скрывает обычный блок на сайте

Tags: веб-программирование

Почему-то Adblock блокирует отображение данного блока на landing. Как решить данную проблему? Сайт на UMI.

```html
<div class="adv">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="div_cont image">
      <img src="/images/temp/big-img2.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="div_cont padd">
      <div class="title">
        <span>Работаем до полного утверждения.</span>
        <h1>Уникально и креативно</h1>
        <p class="t_inf">При создании ваших альбомов мы отвергаем все шаблонные варианты и разрабатываем уникальный дизайн, соответствующий вашим пожеланиям. Также мы проводим 2-3 фотосессии, из которых вы выбираете лучшие фото!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Адблок всё правильно сделал. Вы показываете рекламу, вот он её и заблокировал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<div class="adv">` измените название этого класса так, чтобы оно не начиналось на **ad**

Comment: Спасибо! Только что сам заметил эту ошибку

Comment: @АнтонВласов строго говоря, это не ваша ошибка, а кривые фильтры AdBlock'а.